# CSS needed to make label for jquery slider that follows the slider

Tags: css, jquery-ui, uislider

I am making a jquery slider and I need a box to follow below the slider that contains the value of the slider. The code I have right now places the value of the slider on top of the slider, so what CSS do I need to add to make this information be below the slider?

`$(function() {

```
  $("#slider").slider({
    orientation: "horizontal",
    min: 0,
  max: 60,
  value: 60,
  slide: function(event, ui) {
    var monthYear = numberToDate(ui.value);
    var tooltip = document.createElement("span");
    tooltip.style.position = "absolute";
    tooltip.innerHTML = dateString(monthYear);
    $('.ui-slider-handle').html(tooltip);
      //$("#amount").val(dateString(monthYear));
    },
    change: function(event, ui) {
      changeColor(ui.value);    
    }
  })

  //$("#amount").val($("#slider").slider("value"));
```

}); `

The span `tooltip` contains the information that I am trying to display below the slider, I just need to know what CSS I can use to make it do that.

Here is a jsfiddle of the slider that I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/azrosen92/cPQan/

Answer (score 0):

Can you post a link to it? Or maybe set up a jsFiddle? Otherwise it's not easy to troubleshoot..

The only thing I would change in your code is:

```
$('.ui-slider-handle').html(tooltip);
```

to

`$('.ui-slider-handle').append(tooltip);`

otherwise I can't see a problem